# Linq multiple join if exits

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm strugling to implement this code. If anyone help, will be really appreciated.

```
var result = (from fv in db.UsFavourites.Where(m => m.UserID == currentUserId)
                      join ad in db.CtArticleDetails.Where(m => m.ArticleStatusId == ConfigHelper.Published) on fv.ArticleReferenceID equals ad.ArticleReference
                      join pcs in db.PcPages.Where(m => m.Status == ConfigHelper.Published) on fv.PageReferenceID equals pcs.Reference
                      join prd in db.PrProducts.Where(m => m.ProductStatusID == ConfigHelper.Published) on fv.ProductReferenceID equals prd.ProductReference
                      select new FavouriteModel
                      {
                          FavouriteId = fv.FavouriteID,
                          Title = ad.Title ?? pcs.PageName ?? prd.Name,
                          Url = ad.Title ?? pcs.PageName ?? prd.Name,
                          ArticleReferenceID = (int)fv.ArticleReferenceID,
                          PageReferenceID = (int)fv.PageReferenceID,
                          ProductReferenceID = (int)fv.ProductReferenceID
                      });
```

Basically, I'm trying to join 3 tables as you see: ad, pcs, prd.   If Pcs is not existed, the code should ignore.  Can anyone advice ?

Added db design to make clear : 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking to do a left join on

- `pcs` `db.PcPages`
- `ad`  `db.CtArticleDetails`

`DefaultIfEmpty` is used to make it a left join

```
var result = (from fv in db.UsFavourites.Where(m => m.UserID == currentUserId)
                      from ad in db.CtArticleDetails.Where(m => m.ArticleStatusId == ConfigHelper.Published) 
                                                    .Where(m => fv.ArticleReferenceID == m.ArticleReference)
                                                    .DefaultIfEmpty()
                      from pcs in db.PcPages.Where(m => m.Status == ConfigHelper.Published)
                                            .Where(m => fv.PageReferenceID == m.Reference)
                                            .DefaultIfEmpty()
                      join prd in db.PrProducts.Where(m => m.ProductStatusID == ConfigHelper.Published) on fv.ProductReferenceID equals prd.ProductReference
                      select new FavouriteModel
                      {
                          FavouriteId = fv.FavouriteID,
                          Title = ad.Title ?? pcs.PageName ?? prd.Name,
                          Url = ad.Title ?? pcs.PageName ?? prd.Name,
                          ArticleReferenceID = (int)fv.ArticleReferenceID,
                          PageReferenceID = (int)fv.PageReferenceID,
                          ProductReferenceID = (int)fv.ProductReferenceID
                      });
```

Comment: I think all of pcs, ad and prd need to be left join.